# Determinant of a portioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and $C$ is defined to be

$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}
O&A\\
B&O
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $O$ denotes the zero matrix.

Can I conclude that $O$ needs to be only square matrix of size $n\times n$ because if $O$ has any other size, then it does not make sense?

Can I also then say that $\det(C)=-\det(A)\det(B)$?

If I am wrong, then can you explain why?

Comment: For the first question, yes, both $O$'s have to be $n\times n$. For the upper left one has to have the same number of rows as $A$ and the same number of columns as $B$.

Comment: For the second question, also yes, the determinant of a block matrix is defines the same way. One good way to see it is by looking at diagonal products and noting that each term there is a product of a term from $\det A$ and a term from $\det B$.

Comment: And have a look at the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Comment: Oops I forgot the a $(-1)^n$ in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the example where $A$ and $B$ are both the $2\times2$ identity matrix.  Then you may calculate that $\det(C)$ is $1$, which is not $-\det(A)\det(B)$.  In fact we have in general
$$\det(C)=(-1)^n\det(A)\det(B)\ .$$
Reason: use row-reduction.  If we interchange rows $n$ times we get
$$\det(C)=(-1)^n\det\pmatrix{B&O\cr O&A\cr}\ ,$$
and it's not too hard to show that the matrix on the RHS has determinant $\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it very clear. So if $$C=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\ C&D\end{pmatrix}$$then $$\det(C)\not=\det(A)\det(D)-\det(B)\det(C)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your situation $O$ has to be $n\times n$. As for the determinant, 
$$
\det C=(-1)^n\,\det(A)\,\det(B).
$$
This is because
$$
\begin{bmatrix}O&A\\ B& O\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}O&I\\  I& O\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}B&O\\ O&A\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is also excellent but I had to choose one :)